# BLOB column empty after JDBC insertion

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, blob

I have this code (actually, this is a simplified version of it, obv.)

```
private StreamAndStatement getStatement(File f, String fid, Long dex, String uid, int id)
{
  FileInputStream fis = null;
  PreparedStatement statement;
  statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO BLOBTABLE (FID, FDEX, SFILE, UID, ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
  statement.setString(1, fid);
  statement.setLong(2, dex);
  fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  statement.setBinaryStream(3, fis, file.length());
  statement.setString(4, uid);
  statement.setInt(5, id);

  return new StreamAndStatement(statement, fis);
}

private insertStuff()
{
  File f = new File("/home/user/thisFileExists");
  StreamAndStatement sAndStatement = getStatement(f, "XYZ", 18L, "ABC", 78);
  sAndStatement.getStatement().execute();
  sAndStatement.closeStream();
}
```

StreamAndStatement is as straightforward and obvious as you might imagine.

Now the whole code runs without Oracle yelling at me but the blob just ends up empty...

I am really not messing with the stream at any point in between and as you see, getStatement which creates the stream and the execution of the statement are in two consecutive lines so no tampering...

Answer (score 0):

We first insert the record with an empty blob, then we go in update mode setting its content. As far as I know this is the classical approach. The code can be like the following (DbUtil give us some utility methods):

```
    int insertBlobGettingId(Connection con, int idUpload, InputStream streamFile) {
            int idBlob = DBUtil.getUniqueIdentifier("seq_uploaded_blob", con);
            String insertEmptyBlob = "insert into uploaded_blob (id, FILE_CONTENT) values ("+idBlob+", empty_blob())";
            DBUtil.executeSql(insertEmptyBlob, con);

            if(streamFile != null) {
                String sql = "select file_content from uploaded_blob where id = "+idBlob+" FOR UPDATE ";

                oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet rs = null;
                oracle.sql.BLOB blob = null;
                try{

                    rs = (oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet)DBUtil.openResultSet(sql, con);
                    if(rs.next()){
                        blob = rs.getBLOB("file_content");

                        int chunkSize = blob.getChunkSize();
                        byte[] binaryBuffer = new byte[chunkSize];
                        int bytesRead;
                        int position = 1;

                        while ((bytesRead = streamFile.read(binaryBuffer)) != -1) {
                            blob.putBytes(position, binaryBuffer, bytesRead);
                            position += bytesRead;
                        }

                    } else {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Id "+idBlob+" not found");
                    }

                }catch(Exception e){
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);

                }finally{
                    DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
                }
            }
            return idBlob;
    }
```